# Getting file size of each file on a very large file system

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, filesystems, centos

I have to move the 20TB file system with a couple of million of files to a ZFS file system. So I would like to get an idea of the file sizes in order to make a good block size selection.

My current idea is to `stat --format="%s" each file and then divide the files into bins.

```
#!/bin/bash

A=0 # nr of files <= 2^10
B=0 # nr of files <= 2^11
C=0 # nr of files <= 2^12
D=0 # nr of files <= 2^13
E=0 # nr of files <= 2^14
F=0 # nr of files <= 2^15
G=0 # nr of files <= 2^16
H=0 # nr of files <= 2^17
I=0 # nr of files >  2^17

for f in $(find /bin -type f); do

    SIZE=$(stat --format="%s" $f)

    if [ $SIZE -le 1024 ]; then
    let $A++
    elif [ $SIZE -le 2048 ]; then
    let $B++
    elif [ $SIZE -le 4096 ]; then
    let $C++
    fi
done

echo $A
echo $B
echo $C
```

The problem with this script is that I can't get `find` to work inside a for-loop.

**Question**

How to fix my script?

And is there a better way to get the all the file sizes of a file system?

Comment: Maybe use `awk`... But I am not convinced at all that you should make bins of files of similar sizes...

Comment: What error are you getting with the code you have above?

Comment: @Mat It just doesn't do anything. So it is hard to tell what is wrong.

Comment: It _appears_ not to do anything (and might end up failing). That's just because you're too far away from the disks to hear them churn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you are using command substitution to feed the output of `find` to the `for` loop. Command substitution works by running the command within parentheses (or backticks) to completion, collecting its output, and substituting it in to the script. That doesn't support streaming, meaning the for loop won't run until the `find` scan is completely done, and you'll need lots of memory to buffer the output of `find` too.

Especially because you are scanning many terabytes worth of files, you will want to use something that supports streaming, like a `while` loop:

```
find /bin -type f | while read f; do
    ...
done
```

With something that can stream, your script will at least work, but keep in mind that this technique forces you to invoke an external command (`stat`) once for each and every file that is found. This will incur a lot of process creation, destruction, and startup cost for the `stat` command. If you have GNU find, something that outputs the size of each file right in the `find` command with its `-printf` option for example would perform much better.

Aside: the `let` statements in the body of the loop look wrong. You are expanding the contents of the `$A`, `$B`, and `$C` variables instead of referencing them. You shouldn't use `$` here.

Comment: If I execute your `find` command with an `echo $f` inside it doesn't print anything. It is as if it doesn't enter the loop like like mine.

Comment: Using `find /bin/ -type f -printf "%s\n" > /tmp/all_sizes.txt` is a very interesting idea, and then post-process the output afterwards.

Comment: Yes, and you can also stream that using a pipe so that you don't need to store the intermediate result in a very large temp file.

Answer (score 1):

If just want to find out the number of files between say 100M and 1000M you can do the following

```
find . -size +100M -size -1000M  -type f | wc -l
```

Comment: This is not a good solution as I would need to `stat` each file for each range. Doesn't scale for 20TB.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting actually I think this is a very good alternate solution. You'll have to run this command 9 times with different `-size` parameters in order to match each of your 9 buckets, which means scanning the filesystem 9 times, but each scan will be very fast compared to a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate using dd to read the zfs metadata, which should be contained on the data disks themselves.

That might be a bad suggestion and could result in you wasting time.  But crawling the filesystem with bash is going to take a long time and chew system cpu utilization.

Comment: I'm sorry, no.  Assuming you have time to investigate this option, then I would read the ZFS white papers and design docs, and then begin experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

```
find /bin/ -type f -printf "%s\n" > /tmp/a
```

And then use the following as `script.pl < /tmp/a`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = ();

while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    if    ($_ <= 2**10) { $h{1} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**11) { $h{2} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**12) { $h{4} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**13) { $h{8} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**14) { $h{16} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**15) { $h{32} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**16) { $h{64} += 1}
    elsif ($_ <= 2**17) { $h{128} += 1}
    elsif ($_ >  2**17) { $h{big} += 1}
}

print Dumper \%h;
```

Answer (score 0):

The venerable [du command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) would provide you with sizes more directly.